# Divide and Conquer division algorithm explained

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

I am trying to understand the divide and conquer algorithm that [is used in the GMP bignum arithmetic library](https://gmplib.org/manual/Divide-and-Conquer-Division.html).

The code is very optimised and that makes it somewhat hard to understand. the doc does not really offer an explanation of how it is done.

I understand the concept of divide and conquer for sorting, but I am not sure I understand how it can be used in a division.

How can $x \over y$ be calculated using divide and conquer?

Comment: https://gmplib.org/manual/References.html#References

Comment: Yes, I saw the link to the reference, (it is also on the link I posted), but neither of the books explain how divide and conquer is used in a division.

Comment: I would guess more people at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software  have an interest in libraries, specific implementations.

Comment: It is a much smaller community, but I was try and ask there, thanks